# Working with smart card and token in C#

Tags: c#, token, smartcard

Our company is working with smart cards and tokens and I want to create an easy application to use those cs and tokens.

I want to create a DLL in order to use the methods in the future for another applications.

In the DLL I need those methods:
1. Get all the certificates in the smart card or token connected to the computer.
2. Open the windows "Choose certificates" dialog.
3. Check the smart card or token connceted password.
4. Open the windows "Enter Password" dialog of the provider, and how to know if the password is correct.

I was looking arround internet and I found the CspParameters and the Cryptography namespace. But it seems to be to complicated for my needs.

Is there an easy way to make the methods above?

Using Visual Studio 2012 with C# !!

Comment: Usually you get this dll with the card reader that you use, but if you want to do some specific crypting you will have to use stuff from Cryptograhy namespace.

Comment: that's fine, but I need to know how exactly to use the Cryptograhy namespace, there are a lot of things there and I don't know what to use and how.

Comment: That namespace contains various crypting algorithms from which you can choose, and most of them have their own parameters that you need to provide. Is the data on your smart card crypted? If it is then you need to use the same algorithm, or you won't be able to decrypt it correctly. If not, then pick an algorithm yourself - I once used MD5 crypting algorithm, it was simple enough to implement - take a look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5(v=vs.110).aspx